# Best Way to Save a Recent list for uitableView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, nsarray

Im struggling to get my head around this one.

I currently have a uitableview which is populated from an array.

When the user selects row at index i want to then add that to a tableview in a different view controller.

The cells contain text and images.

I thought about adding it to an array and then saving that array in nsuserdefaults.

But im not convinced that this is the best way to go about it.

Hints,Tips and direction would be greatly received

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an `NSObject` subclass for ivars of type `NSString` and `UIImage`. GIve it a name of your choice. Say `CustomClass`, for instance.

Now, When selecting a row from the table, create an instance of the `CustomClass` you made as above. and pass it to the method, which is invoking `NextViewController`. Here, you have to override `initWithNibName:` method to pass an object to next viewcontroller class.

Hope you are getting my point. This will solve your problem.

Comment: im not sure if i follow Matt, Would you be so kind to provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSCache for this

```
 [cache setObject:yourcellcontaint forKey:someKey];
```

And get it where you want:

```
[cache objectForKey:someKey]
```

Comment: but wouldnt the cache be wiped clean when the application terminates?